# Can I restrict the scope of a Pug mixin to its declaring block so that it cannot be accessed by extending blocks?

Tags: pug

This is a problem I run into frequently, and it makes me wonder if I'm approaching Pug mixins wrong. I have checked the GitHub issues for related conversations.

Given these files:

```
// main.pug

extends base

block content
    include message // or the definition itself
    +message('Outer')
    block inner
```

```
// page.pug

extends main

block inner
    +message('Inner')
```

Pug will give the `inner` block access to the `message` mixin. This is consistent with other scoping rules such as those concerning variables.

I would like to explicitly include mixins within my blocks and pages such that they don't have "knowledge" of the declarations in the blocks that they extend.

My feelings aside, Pug ignores redundant declarations, meaning if you define a mixin that shares a name with a mixin from an extended block, Pug will quietly use the existing mixin. You have to stay aware of all the the mixins from all the blocks you are extending. **EDIT:** I must have misremembered this. In further testing, the later mixin overrides the initial one.

Is this just the way it is, or should I be using mixins differently?

Comment: That's just the way it is.  I've found that if your app becomes this complex where you're running into variable name collisions it's time to refactor anyway and give variables their own namespaced prefixes.  Pug's strength is in simplifying HTML, not building hyper-complex apps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am seeing in boilerplates: Common mixins are included upfront in the base template. Also, see my edit. I was wrong about the behavior.